# MS Access will occasionally remove checkboxes from my Yes/No fields and replace them with 0 and -1

Tags: vba, ms-access, checkbox

My new database is built using a variety of queries and tables. These tables and queries have two checkbox fields that are set for "Test" and "Approved". The way that these come into play is that I have buttons on one form called "ApprovalForm" that open up another form called "ViewForm". The goal was that "ViewForm would change its subform's source object every time one of these buttons is clicked. ApprovalForm closes itself first, then ViewForm opens, then Subform.SourceObject is updated to the query specified by whatever button was clicked.

```
   Private Sub View_NonSize_APL_Click()
On Error GoTo View_NonSize_APL_Click_Err

    DoCmd.Close acForm, ("ApprovalForm")
    DoCmd.OpenForm ("ViewForm")
    Forms!ViewForm!View_Subform.SourceObject = "Query.NonSize - APL View"
    Forms!ViewForm!View_Subform.Form.Requery
    Forms!ViewForm.Form.Requery
    Forms.ViewForm.Caption = "NonSize - APL View"

View_NonSize_APL_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

View_NonSize_APL_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume View_NonSize_APL_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

With the process finished, the final result should be that the fields are populated by the query, which is looking at a table off on the side. The user has no access to the table itself, just that specific select query. However, in rare occasions, the checkboxes will not load correctly, instead displaying as 0s and -1s. What is peculiar about this is that when you click the button on "ViewForm" that leads back to "ApprovalForm" and click the same exact button AGAIN, the checkboxes load correctly.

My guess is that it has something to do with how "ViewForm" loads in, and due to it being a business project, the computer that it is working on is less than optimal. I tried to remedy the situation by using "Requery" and "Refresh" in the code to hopefully reload the process. I have also tried the cumbersome route of having the form close after being loaded and immediately reloading again. (Open the form, load its query, close the form, then open the form again.) That actually proved to ruin the entire process.

Is there anything I can do to counter this problem?